# Disabling entire header for WooCommerce's Storefront theme for a single product's page with CSS?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I've tried doing things like `.page-id-1122 #different-elements-i-saw-in-chrome-inspector-here { display: none; }` without any luck.

Can anyone tell me how I'd accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get your header id and go to your style css, add this code

body.product-template-default.single.single-product.woocommerce.woocommerce-page.customize-support .header-area {
    display: none;
}

Here .header-area will be your header class/id.

Comment: This worked and looked great but for some reason isn't working when I log out

Comment: just use this this remove the class .customize-support

body.product-template-default.single.single-product.woocommerce.woocommerce-page .header-area {
    display: none;
}

Comment: That did it. Cheers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`.page-id-1122 #different-elements-i-saw-in-chrome-inspector-here { display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; }`

Comment: I tried that with `.page-id-5365 .site-header { display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; }`. I've tried hiding the id "masthead" and even the class "side-header" with no luck.